# Unable to sign in to titanium studio in Windows 7

Tags: titanium

I can use titanium studio on my mac.But just can't sign in to titanium in windows.The error is like below:

"The login server is currently unreachable.Please make sure you are online or try again in a few minutes."

Any knows the reason?Thank you

Comment: Do you have a network connection? Check your network connectivity.. Also refer http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/145441/you-will-not-be-able-to-log-into-titaniumstudio-also

Comment: @Anand I checked my network connectiivty and also that link.Looks my envrionment is great,but still can't connect to the IDE.

Comment: Which version of sdk you're using, and Which OS you're using?

Comment: @Anand 3.1.2 and windows 7 32bit

Comment: Try to re-install the the studio. There might occurred some issues while installing the studio.

Comment: @Anand Thank you for your help.I already reinstalled times and times,it just not working.I decide to use Titanium in mac.

Comment: Ok. I have installed the newer version of Titanium Studion in my Windows 7 64 bit machine and windows 8 64 bit machine. It works properly without any issues!!

Comment: @Anand Ok,I think it's the reason about my company's firewall.I will test it again when I got that machine back...

Comment: May be you're right. You need to allow access to Ti Studio

Comment: @Anand maybe it is.hi,btw,do you know why I can't make a tableview scrolled?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19784615/how-to-scroll-the-tableview-located-in-fathers-tableviewandroid